# Aria expanded value read incorrectly by screenreader

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I generate some collapsable div with javascript. I would like the screenreader to indicate whether the div is collapsed or not. I am trying to use the template from https://techservicesillinois.github.io/accessibility/aria-examples/accordion.html:

my code is:

```
var frag = '<div class="accordion"><h3 class="label label--secondary filter__heading" id="' + toggleId + '"><button class="aria-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="' + resultsId + '">' + this.component.display + toggle + '</button></h3>\
                    <div class="filter__body collapse"  style="height: 0px" id="' + resultsId + '">\
                        <ul class="filter__choices">{{FILTERS}}</ul>\
                    </div></div>';
```

All other functionality is correct. In the console, the aria-expanded attribute is added to the h3 and indicates the state correctly, but not used by the screenreader. The SR uses the aria-expanded attribute value from the button, and that for some reason is always "false". How to fix it?

--EDIT for important information--
the accordion behaviour is implemented in js.

--EDIT2 for clarification--
In my code I add the "aria-expanded" attribute to the  element, but when I run the code, the browser inspection shows it always set to "false". Inspector also shows, that this attribute is added to the  element and changed there with the correct value. I don't add it to the h3, as shown in the code, I don't know why this is added.

Comment: Where is `aria-controls` set, to indicate _which_ component this control has expanded?

Comment: @CBroe I edited to add that information. The accordion behaviour is implemented in js (not my code, no idea why it was done like this). So the expanded content is shown or not. I need the button to tell me that.

Comment: _"the accordion behaviour is implemented in js (not my code, no idea why it is done like this)"_ - because it's _necessary_ ...? Mere buttons don't automagically do what is needed here by default, on their own. You said you wanted to do this(?) "with checkboxes", but I can't tell right now whether you mean you want a checkbox-_based_ solution (without JS - which will of course not be very accessible then), or if that just mean your accordion elements will _contain_ some checkboxes (although in that case, this would have been rather superfluous information to begin with.)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, the checkboxes are not important here. The content of the expandable div contains checkboxes. You are right, This information is not needed. I just need to make sure that the screenreader correctly informs the user whether the accordion is expanded or collapsed.

I will edit again to make it clearer.

Comment: @CBroe
Oh, and I added the "aria-controls" to the code but that doesn't change my problem.

Comment: _"In the console, the aria-expanded attribute is added to the h3"_ - can't see that happening on the site you linked to though; the attribute gets toggled on the button, as it should be - and on the `h3`, I don't see any ARIA attributes at all.

Comment: If you don't even need a full accordion, but just _one_ collapsible element - then I would probably rather use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe I also cannot see this behaviour in the site I linked. But I can see that when I run my code. So there is obviously an error in my code. And I cannot see that.
" If you don't even need a full accordion, but just one collapsible element" - I need a full accordion, the rest of the content is generated. I am not in position to touch the rest of the code, I just need an aria-expanded attribute set correctly, And this is my problem.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: The shared markup is ok, The error must be in the code. Can you share the JS code? If it’s actually setting the attribute on the `<h3>`, than that’s the error and should easily be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few conflicting statements in your question:

> *I would like the screenreader to indicate whether the **div** is collapsed or not.*

> *the aria-expanded attribute is added to the **h3***

If you want the **<div>** to announce if it's collapsed or not, then setting `aria-expanded` on the **<h3>** isn't going to help you.  You'd need to set it on the <div>.

However, neither of those statements is the correct way to implement an accordion. `aria-expanded` must be set on an **interactive** element, of which neither a <div> nor an <h3> are interactive.  `aria-expanded` must be set on the <button> and its value must be toggled between "true" and "false", based on the user expanding or collapsing the section.  That's exactly how your [example URL](https://techservicesillinois.github.io/accessibility/aria-examples/accordion.html) is working.

If you are not hearing "expanded" or "collapsed" announced when you navigate to the button, then there is a problem in your code, but you have not posted enough code for us to diagnose the problem.

Note that your example URL bases its code on the [Accordion Design Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/) in the [Authoring Practice Guide](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/).

Comment: Thank you. I do have my aria-expanded on the button element (as in my code provided) and still don't hear the "expanded" and "collapsed". I'll look further into what could be wrong.

Comment: You should update your question so that your description matches your code.

Comment: I added the information. My description matches the code, but I understand it is not clear enough, sorry for that. The thing is that what is happening in the browser inspector doesn't match my code and I cannot understand why. But I understand from your comment that the problem is likely somewhere else, not in my code.

Comment: Sorry I can’t provide more information given what you have posted. I use `aria-expanded` all the time and it works great.

Comment: Your comment helped me to find an issue - it was in javascript code rather than HTML. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I’m glad you resolved it. Do you want to add an update to your question on whar the problem was?